# Image sticking using jssor slider

Tags: jssor

I've implemented the nearby partial visible image slider demo into the site, pulling out dynamic data for the image etc, I'm having an issue with the image sticking to the left side.

See example here: http://www.dehelvi.com/index.php/seating.html

Answer (score 0):

please use `$Align` option to adjust position for current slide to stay.

```
var options = {
    ...,
    $Align: 100,
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have already set the parking position, please take a look at the example to see exactly what i mean, its working with most slides but one of the images refuses to disappear for a couple of slides.

Comment: I think there is a bug. The `$ParkingPosition` won't work with `$Loop: 0`. Please set `$Loop` to 1 or 2.

Comment: i have tried your suggestion but its still sticking, not sure why.